# Attach image to Tweet

Tags: javascript, twitter, media

Is't possible to attach a image to my tweet without the API?

Like adding a parameter to the share ??

`https://twitter.com/share?source=tweetbutton&text=mytexthere&url=example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You would definitely need to use their API or at-least 3rd party plugins that use twitter API.

Reference : https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059